# Change text using CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a question.

In [this site](https://www.llantasavance.com) I'm trying to translate the text "SEE COLLECTION" in the section that looks like this:

[VISUAL GUIDE OF SECTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxrGW.png)

I tried using Loco Translate (site is a WordPress), but it doesn't appear on the translatable text elements, and I can't edit the HTML file for security reasons.

I need the text to say: "Ver Productos".

Could someone help me?

Comment: While it may be possible, keep in mind the purpose of CSS is to STYLE content not update or replace it.

Comment: Yes, indeed I told that to the customer. They have previous bad experience changing the direct html of the theme, so that's why they told me to do it on css. I really thank you for your comment, it is better to stick to "best practices".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are already using the `::after` pseudo element to do your underine. This means you can't hide the text which is already there in the anchor tag. Try this solution

```
  .store-mart-lite-cat-prod-content .store-mart-lite-cat-prod-btn a {
     font-size: 0px; /* workaround */
  }

  .store-mart-lite-cat-prod-content .store-mart-lite-cat-prod-btn a::before {
     content: 'Ver Productos';
     font-size: 14px;
  }
```

Comment: Becky, THANK YOU, this solved my problem. I got sick and couldn't answer sooner. You have my respect and sincere thanks. Please, keep helping the Stack Overflow community. :D